# How do I check which features of modern javascript( ES2015++, ES2018, ES2019) are implemented in the browser?

Tags: javascript

I was reading the proposal of ES2019 and I'm very interested to use the newly added features in this blog [here](https://medium.com/@selvaganesh93/javascript-whats-new-in-ecmascript-2019-es2019-es10-35210c6e7f4b). However I've been trying to search the reference of which browser has implemented which features but I can't seem to find it.

The closest I can get is to look at the javascript engine of each browser in [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECMAScript#Conformance) and go to the github repo but still there're not much information that I can get. I'm developing on react and have been using babel under the hood but it will be nice to understand the underlying implementation of most browser and why it is not implemented yet. Should we not care about that anymore because we have babel? Can anyone help me explain?

Cheers

Comment: cainuse or MDN both has info about methods supported in which browser and versions as well

Comment: For example go to google type in `js promises` then you go to the result from MDN and scroll almost to the bottom there you see witch browsers support this

Answer (score 0):

You should care, even though Babel is a lifesaver.

I always check caniuse.com: https://caniuse.com/#feat=mdn-javascript_builtins_array_flat